# Admob interstitial ads - Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready

Tags: ios, admob, ads, interstitial

Is this code correct to implement an interstitial ad?

[image]

Because when I launch it I get this,

```
<Google> Cannot present interstitial.  It is not ready.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to wait until the ad loads successfully and only then present it in case of Interstitial ads. Otherwise the ads wont show up.

To do this conform to the `GADInterstitialDelegate` protocol and set your view controller as the delegate of interstitial_.

```
interstitial_.delegate = self;
```

Then implement `interstitialDidReceiveAd` as follows.

```
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    [interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

For more reference, please check [Interstitials ads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios)

Comment: So should I just copy all of this and implement somewhere? Sorry, I'm new to all this. @Rahul Patel

http://i.gyazo.com/ba303f5cfb14042559cf59a93bb491f3.png

Comment: Yes you need to implement in your viewController. This method would be fire automatically when something happens regarding ads

Comment: Note, proper method declaration is `- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial;`

Comment: I've tried a few different things.. but I can't get the interstitialWillDismissScreen implementation in Swift. Can anyone translate this solution to Swift?

Comment: Should you not change the declaration of your Objective-C class to indicate you conform to the `<GADInterstitialDelegate>` protocol? (ie write `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GADInterstitialDelegate>` for the viewcontroller that will be the delegate?)

Comment: @bobobobo : Yes. It is explained as simple text in answer.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0

in `viewDidLoad()` or `createAndLoadInterstitial()`

```
interstitial.delegate = self
```

then implement

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want load google interstitial ads again on next page or current page use below code..

//On view Did load add following line on your next page or current page view controller.m

```
self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
```

//create following  methods on your next page or current page view controller.m

```
- (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial {
    GADInterstitial *interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"];
    interstitial.delegate = self;
    [interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    return interstitial;
}
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial 
{
//leave this method as empty    
}
```

now you will able to receive ads will shown

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to use `interstitialDidReceiveAd` method. This is not recommended by admob documentation. Maybe you can use `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `viewDidLoad()`

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isReady)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        mInterstitialAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0

in `viewDidLoad()`

Make sure to set the delegate for your View Controller by doing so

`interstitial.delegate = self`

then in the delegate methods you could implement the following

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
}
```